# I can't find FireFox in the AppCenter of Loki, although I have installed it

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

Why can't I find Firefox in the AppCenter?
[image]

Not only Firefox, but also other non-elementary Apps.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the AppCenter only shows apps whitin the Ubuntu Store and sources. If those apps you have aren't on the official repos they won't show up there.

Comment: The Firefox is from the Ubuntu Store.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the repositories included with Loki.
2. Have an AppData file that conforms to specification OR
3. Have a .desktop file that conforms to specification.

That said, Firefox appears in my AppCentre.

Comment: You mean I have to include other repositories? It is installed from the official repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt update
```

This may be related to an unfixed bug:

> [AppCenter is empty if apt update has never been run [$30]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1615270)
>
> Expectation:
>   AppCenter fires up packagekitd and updates the software catalog transparently in the background when the session starts up
>
> Reality:
>   AppCenter only shows data for the pre-installed packages. packagekitd never fixes it. AppCenter is useless until you open a Terminal and manually run apt update

Comment: I did run apt update.