# Is there a way to debug AppCenter? if yes where are the logs?

Tags: appcenter

I'm trying to enable debug in appcenter to figure out why mine has the updates page empty. I saw the option -d in App Center from command line, but where the debug logs are saved?

Thanks.

Comment: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/9795/170

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppCenter is always ran on startup with a "silent" argument (`appcenter --silent`) which makes it not show the window, silently load the database and update the cache to e.g: show the notification to the user that there are updates available.

When you're launching appcenter from command line when a silent instance is already running, you are simply invoking the `GLib.Application.activate ()` method on the existing instance which is not really what you want in this case. 
See: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/appcenter/appcenter/view/head:/src/Application.vala#L97

**You can just kill the current instance with `killall appcenter` and start debugging it with `appcenter -d`, `gdb appcenter` or whatever you are using to do so.**

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'll try to execute with -d and see if i can figure out why the updates page are still empty.

Comment: I'm also trying to do this, but the command appcenter is not found.